# How do I replicate what this query does in google sheets in excel using averageif or filter?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, filter

```
=AVERAGE(query({JAN!A2:E},"select Col5 where Col1 = '"&A2&"'"))
```

My workbook has drop down lists with names in it, and another drop down list for a score between 0 and 100.

This formula is meant to grab multiple entries under the same name. It works beautifully in sheets but I don't know how to get it to do what I need in excel since I cant use Query Language and I'm pretty new to this.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate average with `AVERAGEIF()` function like-

```
=AVERAGEIF(A2:A50000,A2,E2:E50000)
```

If you want to use `FILTER()` function then could try-

```
=AVERAGE(FILTER(E2:E50000,A2:A50000=A2))
```